# Which CPU should I use in my first scratch 486 build?

Tags: processor

I want to build a PC; not like a gaming rig, but instead, a computer from **scratch**.

There's a great set of videos [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LnzuMJLZRdU&list=PLowKtXNTBypFbtuVMUVXNR0z1mu7dp7eH)), but instead of the MOS 6502, a clone processor to make computing history, a 486-based processor. I automatically assume it would be easier if I used a processor with a DIP 40 socket instead of something with a ton of pins. It both just has less pins, which would be easier, and would be much easier for prototyping. I also need something power-efficient, because I plan to eventually put it into a laptop form factor.

Not related to my processor question, but also, if there is a better site to post this question, please tell me. I barely ever ask questions on Stack Exchange. Anyways, suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This list of [CPUs and their sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_socket#List_of_x86_CPU_sockets_and_slots) shows you would be limited to two very historical CPUs indeed, the [8088](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8088) and [8086](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8086), if you use a DIP40 socket.

Neither of those are 486-based, nor will they will execute the full 486 instruction set. To run the full 486 instruction set, you'd need a PGA socket (of which there are many, listed in the first link in the first sentence) or a slot (op cit.).

I was repairing PCs, and teaching dealers how to repair them, back when CPUs came in slots, and I will tell you PGA sockets gave us a *lot* less trouble than slot-based CPUs.